# Cloud Services - EC2 vs. GAE vs. Lunacloud vs. Jelastic vs.

Tags: java, google-app-engine, amazon-ec2, cloud, jelastic

I am planning to program a software (in java), which will be (hopefully) used very much. In the beginning I may run it on my own server, but if it becomes popular my server will most likly crash.

So my plan is to program it for a cloud service like Amazon EC2, Google App Engine, Lunacloud or others.

The application will not have a gui for now. It will concentrate on SOAP or JMS (or something like that) and should store a lot of data in a relational database (PostgreSQL would be nice).

Since I am new to the cloud services, I tried a little bit with GAE. The main use is easy, but as soon as I use JPA and ManyToMany-Relations GAE is shit. Also making a SOAP or JMS Server in GAE is not simple.

Since I lost my weekend with trying GAE, I thought it would be a good idea to ask the community.

Which cloud service will fit best for my requirements? What are the benefits and differences between these services? What else can you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is question is too wide open to provide a good answer, but here is some tips that should help.

There is a difference between platform as a service (GAE, Jelastic, Heroku) and Infrastructure as a Service (EC2).

In the platform as a service category, you have more of an automated infrastructure, and often very little visibility of the underlying components. This can make things easier from a developer perspective, but it has its downsides. You are often locked into how a provider works and it may be difficult to switch. You may also have limitations as to what you can do with your application.

In the Infrastructure as a Service category, you get access to virtual machines that you can configure and automate yourself. You have more flexibility on this type of platform, but you are generally expected to handle more of the work yourself. EC2 does have its own version of platform as a service with elastic beanstalk.

Comment: So, what would you choose for my purpose? It seems that Jelastic is pretty nice and easy scaling by the cloudlets and compared to Heroku it is cheaper.

Answer (score 0):

i would recoomend also heroku because it does not have a traffic limit and you can run a basic instance for free. if you dont need nosql dbs and extra software it will be very cheap and the unlimited traffic is good for your webservices. Gae has is own filestructure so i can understand your problems with your db structure very good. heroku and ec2 does not restrict your plans but ec2 is generally expensive if you dont plan to scale up and down often. heroku gets also very expensive when you want to add extra software  and scale up. i dont know if youre able to scale up as good as with ec2 if you want to use jelastic.

another but complex approach would be renting some normal root servers with unlimited traffic where one instance act as load balancer but you would have to do the configuration by yourseld

Comment: For me it seems very difficult to see through what you get and what you have to pay. Heroku e.g. seems very expensive to me.

Comment: In terms of pricig Jelastic really seems promising as it automatucally allocates the physical resources each application needs. Besides the price on the service depends on the Hosting Provider you choose, so you have a variety of choices here.Jelastic offers a great number of unrivaled features. Here is a useful video on how to easily project and check the cost you pay: http://jelastic.com/pricing. And if you want a bright comparison to other platforms read the benefits right here: http://blog.jelastic.com/2012/02/27/google-app-engine-vs-jelastic/

Comment: I already found the comparison. There is also one for  [Heroku](http://blog.jelastic.com/2012/02/09/jelastic-versus-heroku/) and  [Beanstalk](http://blog.jelastic.com/2013/04/16/elastic-beanstalk-vs-jelastic/)